# Manipulate fragments at runtime from one class

Tags: android, android-fragments

I put a couple fragments into one Activity like this

```
private void createFragmentList() {
    Resources r = getResources();
    String packageName = getPackageName();
    fragmentList = new Fragment[]{
            new Fragment_One,
            new Fragment_Two,
            ...
    };

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    for (int arrayIndex=0, fragmentNumber=1; fragmentNumber <= numberOfFragments; arrayIndex++, fragmentNumber++){
        fragmentTransaction.replace(r.getIdentifier("fragment" + fragmentNumber, "id", packageName), fragmentList[arrayIndex]);
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Now I want to do some changes on this fragments.
For example if I try to hide a button

```
/* will be called from onCreate() */
private void customizeFragmentList(){ 
    Button backBtn = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.backBtn);
    backBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

But the app will crash if I run this method.
So is there a possibility to make changes from the main class where all fragments comes together?
It would be redundant work if I would have to do this in each fragment class seperatly

Comment: where is this button backBtn in activity or fragment

Comment: it's in the fragment

Answer (score 1):

Create public method inside your fragment

```
public void customizeFragmentList(){ 
   Button backBtn = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.backBtn);
   backBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

and call it like this from your Activity

```
((Fragment_One)fragmentList.get(0)).customizeFragmentList();
```

**Note:** this example is only valid for first fragment. If you want to manipulate other fragments you need to cast each fragment seperatly

Comment: sounds like a interesting idea. But so I will have to make this method in every Fragment. Sounds like a lot redudant code.

Comment: @WeSt Im sorry. I thought you used list to store fragments. In case you are using array try `fragmentList[0]`

Comment: tried your solution but get the same crash/error `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference` and yes there is a AppCompatButton with the id "backbtn" in the fragment

Comment: @WeSt this is giving you error because `this` is null. My solution to this would be to create backBtn instance inside onCreateVew of your fragment, not inside this method, because it seems you can't access it. Unfortunatly i can't give any more details as I don't know your fragment's code

Comment: tried with `backBtn = (Button) fragment_one.findViewById(R.id.backBtn);` and `public void customizeFragment(){
        backBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }`
but still get the error: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference`

Don't understand why it's null

Comment: @WeSt When you inflate view inside Fragment's  OnCreateView you get `View view = inflater.inflate()...` you need to initiate buttom like this inside oncreateview `backBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(int)`...

Comment: the `View view` is in this case the `View fragment_one`

Comment: Well it might be because fragments are not inflated yet

Comment: thats a bit strange. If I set `Log.i("",backBtn.toString());` in the customizeFragment method it's a NullPointerException but if I put it in the onCreateView right after the allocation it loggs the right information. But the `Button backBtn;` is global

Comment: anyway thanks for your help, maybe you could upvote the question because I realy need a answer for this